# How to use multiple if statement in Laravel blade page

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, conditional-statements, laravel-blade

I can use the if statement to filter the data. Not show data according to condition if `$users`, `$businesses` and `$user_psb` two thing not equal to `null` show first condition data and else show second condition and all other not check.
**Here Is My code**

```
  <!--begin::Progress-->
                    {{-- First Condition --}}
                    @if ($users != null && $businesses != null && $user_psb != null)
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center w-200px w-sm-300px flex-column mt-3">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100 mt-auto mb-2">
                                <span class="fw-bold fs-6 text-gray-400">Profile Completion</span>
                                <span class="fw-bolder fs-6">100%</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="h-5px mx-3 w-100 bg-light mb-3">
                                <div class="bg-success rounded h-5px" role="progressbar" style="width:100%;"
                                    aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{-- Scond Condition --}}
                    @elseif($users != null && $user_psb != null)
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center w-200px w-sm-300px flex-column mt-3">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100 mt-auto mb-2">
                                <span class="fw-bold fs-6 text-gray-400">Profile Completion</span>
                                <span class="fw-bolder fs-6">60%</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="h-5px mx-3 w-100 bg-light mb-3">
                                <div class="bg-warning rounded h-5px" role="progressbar" style="width:60%;"
                                    aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{-- Third Condition --}}
                    @elseif($users != null && $businesses != null)
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center w-200px w-sm-300px flex-column mt-3">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100 mt-auto mb-2">
                                <span class="fw-bold fs-6 text-gray-400">Profile Completion</span>
                                <span class="fw-bolder fs-6">80%</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="h-5px mx-3 w-100 bg-light mb-3">
                                <div class="bg-primary rounded h-5px" role="progressbar" style="width:80%;"
                                    aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center w-200px w-sm-300px flex-column mt-3">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100 mt-auto mb-2">
                                <span class="fw-bold fs-6 text-gray-400">Profile Completion</span>
                                <span class="fw-bolder fs-6">40%</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="h-5px mx-3 w-100 bg-light mb-3">
                                <div class="bg-danger rounded h-5px" role="progressbar" style="width: 40%;"
                                    aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <!--end::Progress-->
```

How can I show data according to my condition?

Comment: Your logic is really wrong, its overriding each other

Comment: so how can I correct this code

Comment: its hard to do that with the current structure, whats more important? $user_psb or $businesses? the way it is right now, if $user_psb is okay, it will go to 60% before checking business

Comment: For starters, you can remove duplicate conditions by using nested conditions. First, start with the outside condition: @if ($users != null). If you are satisfied with the result, you can go on with the implementation of the nested conditions. And don't forget to test after applying each condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
@if($users != null) 
    @if($businesses != null && $user_psb != null) 
         // write code snippets
    @elseif($user_psb != null)
        //  write code snippets
    @elseif($businesses != null)
        // write code snippets
    @else
        // write code snippets
    @endif
@endif
```